# Passive sentence

Tags: passive-voice

> 1.The application has been written by Peter in his home.
>   2.The application has been written in Peter's home by him.

Above which one sentence is grammatical correct and how?

Comment: Did you mean to write *Peater's home* in the second sentence?

Comment: Both are are correct

Answer (score 1):

> which sentence is grammatically correct?

There's a difference between a grammatical sentence and an optimally constructed one. Both of these sentences seem to pass the test of being grammatical.

However, could they be improved?

1. Has the application been completed? If so, then the simple past indicates it better.

> The application was written by Peter.
>   The application was written by Peter in his home.

2. The active voice is often preferable to the passive:

> Peter wrote the application.
>   Peter wrote the application in his home.